# Logic errors in "odd or even" game

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes when I pick `odd`, and the result is `odd` it gives me that the computer won but it's wrong.

Also the scores aren't working, the score always prints `1`.

```
import random

options = ["odd", "even"]
user_wins = 0
comp_wins = 0

while True:
    user_answer = input("Choose odd or even. ").lower()
    if user_answer not in options:
        print("Try again.")
        quit()
    user_answer2 = input("Choose a number larger than zero. ")
    if user_answer2.isdigit():
        user_answer2 = int(user_answer2)
        if user_answer2 <= 0:
            print("Type a number larger than zero. ")
            quit()
    else:
        print("Type a number next time.")
        quit()
    comp_pick = random.randint(0, 10)
    if user_answer == "odd":
        print("Computer picked even and its number is", comp_pick)
    else:
        print("Computer picked odd and its number is", comp_pick)
    total = user_answer2 + comp_pick
    if total % 2 == 0:
        result = "even"
    else:
        result = "odd"
    if result == "even" and user_answer == "even":
        print("The result is", total, "You won!")
        user_wins =+ 1
    else:
        print("The result is", total, "Computer won!")
        comp_wins =+ 1
    print("Your score:", user_wins)
    print("Computer score:", comp_wins)
```

Comment: Sorry i'm a bit confused - what's the game supposed to do? also, I didn't get why you were summing both scores, but again I could be missing something.

Comment: The only way the user wins is if they pick even, and the total is even.  I think you want the user to win if `result == user_answer`.

Comment: In your own words, what does `if result == "even" and user_answer == "even":` mean? If the user picked "odd" and the result was "odd", will this condition be satisfied? Therefore, will the code inside the block run? Therefore, will the code claim that the user won?

Comment: "Also the scores aren't working, the score always prints 1." In your own words, what does `user_wins =+ 1` mean? In your own words, what does `user_wins += 1` mean? Do you see how those two things are different? Which one does your code use? Which one should it use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that [you are expected to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Obviously it's not going to work to search the Internet for something like this, but you can learn some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skills and apply them. Also please note that you are only supposed to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can't win if you choose `odd` because of your last `if` statement:

```
if result == "even" and user_answer == "even":
```

which only lets you win if you choose `even`. You could try changing it to

```
if result == user_answer:
```

2. `comp_wins =+ 1` is the same as `comp_wins = +1` which is the same as `comp_wins = 1`. You must have meant:

```
comp_wins += 1
```

Same applies to `user_wins =+ 1`.